# Overloading standard  getters

Tags: yii

I want to make a custom getter that should return two fields of the model instead of one. I have the attribute name like `first_name`. And the getter I am making is

```
public function getFirstName(){
        return 1;
}
```

And then I try to get it called in a CDetailView like this

```
'client.first_name:raw:Client',
```

But it returns the standard attribute of the model. How to do it right?

Comment: is client a related model? or the current model? it seems to be a related model right?

Comment: Yes, there is a relation between two models, the Client and the other one.

Comment: ok, i think i have a solution, lemme type. one more thing the getter is in the client model right?

Comment: after a bit of testing, i realized that my solution will not work for related models, sorry! it had involved overriding the `__get($name)` method, which anyway seemed like too much of a hack. could you however tell me exactly what you want to return in the custom getter? maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii's order of operations to retrieve an attribute is as follows:

- AR attribute
- public variable
- custom getter

I'm not sure whether AR attributes or public variables are pulled first, but I do know that if either of them exist, your custom getter won't be called.

If you already have a first_name attribute (from AR), then you'll need to use a different name for your getter and use that.